# How to return multiple object form the js function

Tags: javascript

I have a function like below. When I create a new object of the function like this:

```
var newArray = new ArrayCollection ();
```

In the `newArray` I want to access the function property and class like this:

```
var first= newArray[0]
```

Instead of:

```
var first = newArray.Collections[0]
```

And:

```
newArray.add("a");
```

How to I modify the function to do this?

```
ArrayCollection = function ()
{
    this.Collections = new Array();

    this.add = function ( value )
    {
     ....
    };
    this.remove = function ( value )
    {
       .... 
    };
    this.insert = function ( indx, value )
    {
      ....
    };
    this.clear = function ()
    {   ...

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, can't understand your question. Answer to title: just return a list ``return [firstObject, secondObject];``. Answer to the rest of the post (it seems to be pretty unrelated to title): make your collection class use ``Array`` as prototype, or alter Array's prototype as Emissary suggests. (By the way, please consider accepting some answers people provided to your other questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve like this

```
ArrayCollection = function () {
    this.Collections = new Array();
    this.length = 0;

    this.add = function (value) {
        this[this.length] = value;
        this.length++;
    };

    this.remove = function (value) {
        // remove from array
        this.length--;
    };

    this.insert = function (indx, value) {
        // insert to array
        this.length++;
    };

    this.clear = function () {
        // clear array
        this.length = 0;
    };
};

var newArray = new ArrayCollection();
newArray.add('ll');
newArray.add('bb');
newArray.add('cc');

alert(newArray[0])
alert(newArray[1])
alert(newArray[2])
```